# Homebrew error occurred when I command "brew cask install virtualbox" or "brew cask search google-chrome"

Tags: macos, virtualbox, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I'm trying to install virtual box with brew-cask, but That returns this kind of error and I cannot install virtualbox. I use MacOSX Lion 10.7.5 and homebrew 0.9.5, ruby 2.1.0-p0

I've described the process in Terminal below.

First of all, `brew tap` command is succeeded.

```
    $ brew tap phinze/cask
    Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/phinze/homebrew-cask'...
    remote: Reusing existing pack: 32538, done.
    remote: Counting objects: 36, done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done.
    remote: Total 32574 (delta 16), reused 2 (delta 0)
    Receiving objects: 100% (32574/32574), 11.72 MiB | 379 KiB/s, done.
    Resolving deltas: 100% (19138/19138), done.
    Tapped 1 formula
    It looks like you tapped a private repository. To avoid entering your
    credentials each time you update, you can use git HTTP credential caching
    or issue the following command:

      cd /usr/local/Library/Taps/phinze/homebrew-cask
      git remote set-url origin git@github.com:phinze/homebrew-cask.git
```

Second, I've already installed brew-cask as below

```
    $ brew install brew-cask
    Warning: brew-cask-0.35.0 already installed
```

Third, when I tried to install virtualbox, but it returns this kind of error, and I cannot get install the Virtualbox.

```
    $ brew cask install virtualbox
    ==> Removing legacy Tap
    Error: No available cask for virtualbox
```

Comment: Hey Anon, I'm just confirm the appearance of `virtualbox.rb`. There ARE `virtualbox.rb`. Is this a problem in repository of brew-cask? Can I correct this with pulling another branch?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the previous comment/answer... Running it with the new repository tells me `virtualbox` is downloading... Although I haven't finished downloading it yet...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The homebrew-cask repository [has moved](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask). Did you try:

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew install brew-cask
brew cask install virtualbox
```

instead of phinz?

Update:

As Jon Nalley points out, `brew install brew-cask` is now [deprecated](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask#important-december-2015-update-homebrew-cask-will-now-be-kept-up-to-date-together-with-homebrew-see-15381-for-details-if-you-havent-yet-run-brew-uninstall---force-brew-cask-brew-update-to-switch-to-the-new-system):

> Important December 2015 update: Homebrew-Cask will now be kept up to date together with Homebrew (see #15381 for details). If you haven’t yet, run `brew uninstall --force brew-cask; brew update` to switch to the new system.

Comment: Thank you Annon! I just tried `brew tap caskroom/cask` but I cannot install as `brew install brew-cask` It returns `Error: No available formula for brew-cask ` error.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but before following the steps to install brew-cask, try doing a clean install: `brew untap brew-cask`, `brew uninstall cask`.

Comment: After re-install of brew-cask, I can install virtualbox etc..!!! Thank you so much Anon!

Comment: `brew uninstall brew-cask` - `brew tap caskroom/cask` - `brew install brew-cask` this worked for me.

Comment: I believe `brew install brew-cask` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask#important-december-2015-update-homebrew-cask-will-now-be-kept-up-to-date-together-with-homebrew-see-15381-for-details-if-you-havent-yet-run-brew-uninstall---force-brew-cask-brew-update-to-switch-to-the-new-system).

Comment: @JonNalley: I added an update reflecting the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew install brew-cask
brew cask install virtualbox
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I got the "multiple taps" error:

```
~ $ brew install brew-cask
Error: Formulae found in multiple taps:
 * caskroom/cask/brew-cask
 * phinze/cask/brew-cask
```

Then, I included the full (caskroom) path to brew-cask and it worked:

```
 brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
 brew cask install virtualbox
```

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
brew install homebrew/completions/brew-cask-completion
```

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2021, the answer to this question is to use the cask command as below:

```
brew install --cask <anypackage>
```

For example:

```
brew install --cask virtualbox
```