# Cannot install docker on OS X Version 10.9.5

Tags: docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I first tried installing VirtualBox by downloading "VirtualBox 5.0 for OS X hosts (amd64)" from [the VirtualBox download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), and then installed boot2docker and docker via brew.

The first apparent issue appeared when creating the boot2docker-vm image:

```
$ boot2docker init

2015/07/27 21:38:13 Creating VM boot2docker-vm...
2015/07/27 21:38:13 Apply interim patch to VM boot2docker-vm (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12748)
2015/07/27 21:38:13 Failed to modify VM "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1
```

Launching the VirtualBox manager application I can see the boot2docker-vm machine "Running", but looking at the log I see something like this which appears to indicate that the boot2docker-vm "machine" failed to boot:

```
00:00:04.169546 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=1, bootseq=4231
00:00:04.169711 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:04.170101 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=2, bootseq=0423
00:00:04.170490 Guest Log: BIOS: CDROM boot failure code : 0002
00:00:04.170800 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from CD-ROM failed
00:00:04.171190 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=3, bootseq=0042
00:00:04.171795 Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=80
00:00:04.172304 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Hard Disk 0 failed
00:00:04.172706 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=4, bootseq=0004
00:00:04.172991 Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from LAN...
00:00:04.191271 Display::handleDisplayResize(): uScreenId = 0, pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0, flags=0x1
00:00:06.446949 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from LAN failed
00:00:06.448852 Guest Log: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.
```

I uninstalled everything and then tried downloading and installing from [boot2docker download page](https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/releases/tag/v1.7.1), which installs VirtualBox, boot2docker, and docker all in one go. But I still see the same problem indicated above (the boot2docker-vm machine fails to boot).

I'm reluctant to make big changes to the OS X version on my laptop, since my hardware is old. But I'll try the installation sequence on a more modern machine and see if it works there.

Has anyone managed to make docker work on OS X Version 10.9.5?

**EDIT** (adding additional information which comments suggest might be relevant):

My machine has:

- 2.26GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- 4Gb of RAM (1067 MHz DDR3)
- NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB
- OS X 10.9.5

I installed everything as the primary User (not root) on my system.

And the versions of everything which I installed are:

- VirtualBox 4.3.30 r101610
- boot2docker version 1.7.1
- docker version 1.7.1

Comment: Looks permission issue, did you init boot2docker with `sudo` or by `root`?

Comment: What's your CPU? Does it support virtualization? I had something similar on an old laptop..

Answer (score 3):

This [issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/525) on github might be of help (Latest version of virtual box 4.3.x works fine in the issue described). Though I would suggest to use `docker-machine`. Below are the steps ([Installation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)):

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
$ eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
```

And then you can use docker commands as usual.

Comment: The linked issue was very helpful. I was able to use some of the suggestions and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796448/homebrew-error-occured-when-i-command-brew-cask-install-virtualbox-or-brew-ca) to get boot2docker up and running. I'll see if I can follow this path first to getting the rest of the system working - then I'll try docker-machine as you suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some of the comments in [the github issue suggested by nash_ag](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/525) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796448/homebrew-error-occured-when-i-command-brew-cask-install-virtualbox-or-brew-ca) pointed me in the right direction.

This is the sequence of steps I used to get VirtualBox, boot2docker, docker, and docker-machine working in my environment (where $USERNAME is my primary OS X User, who installed VirtualBox), with several wrong turns elided, and most output omitted:

```
$ rm -rf /Users/$USERNAME/VirtualBox\ VMs/

$ boot2docker delete
(ran VirtualBox Uninstall script from my desktop)
...

$ brew tap caskroom/cask
...

$ brew update
...

$ brew install brew-cask
...

$ brew cask install virtualbox
...

$ VBoxManage -v
5.0.0r101573

$ boot2docker -v
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.7.1
Git commit: 8fdc6f5

$ VBoxManage list vms
(nothing)

$ boot2docker init -v
...

$ boot2docker up
...

$ eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"
(writes .pem files)

$ brew install docker-machine
...

$ docker-machine -v
docker-machine version 0.3.1 (HEAD)

$ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM

$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
...

$ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
dev             virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376

$ VBoxManage list vms
"boot2docker-vm" {99d5c5c1-e7cc-49bf-93c7-b0cbf626d62c}
"dev" {341fd11e-86f9-46ca-89e6-39ee78458a4b}

$ eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"

$ docker run -d -p 8000:80 nginx
...

$ curl $(docker-machine ip dev):8000
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

At this point things appear to be working well enough for me to use the "standard" docs/instructions for docker and docker-machine, so my original problem is solved.